# check value before update in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing the stored procedure, if account is lock(Y) then unlock (N)
But before that i want check,if it already unlock, then i want to give TRUE or FALSE message.

Below is update query

```
    create procedure sp_test
@lock = char(1)
    as 
    begin
     set nocount on;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

        update table1 set isLock= @Lock where id=1
    END
```

Comment: It just fails as  @Lock is not defined.

Comment: Just add "and lock <> lock" in WHERE clause. It has no sense to check prior to update because in between your chack and update the value can be changed by someone else

Comment: And there is no reason to open transaction, update already does it. Your sp opens a transaction and never commit/rollback it, it will prevent log truncation. Never open tran without commit/rollback it.

Comment: lock is column name. now i changed to isLock to remove confusion

Comment: @sepupic what are saying it is fine but how we can check before update

Comment: You have to DECLARE lock CHAR(1), then set it to something first, eh?  Alternatively, DECLARE lock CHAR(1) = SomeValue.  (I couldn't add the at sign).

Comment: Why are you using a char(1) here? This should be the bit datatype. Not really sure what you want as output here though.

Answer (score 1):

Update only when current value is different and check if any row was updated

```
    update table1 
    set isLock= @Lock 
    where id = 1 and (isLock is null or isLock != @Lock);
    if (@@rowcount = 1)
     -- the row was changed
    else
     --  no change
```

Answer (score 0):

you can Use  [OUTPUT Clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), it can apply also on multiple rows

```
DECLARE @state TABLE (isLock BIT)
update table1 set isLock= @Lock OUTPUT Deleted.IsLock INTO @state where id=1
-- check @state table variable
```